# Multiple actions were found that match the request But WebApiConfig is set

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i'm using asp.net web api. And my problem is "Multiple actions were found that match the request" but i set route template already and in my controller i have 2 POST action

```
**WebApiConfig**
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
```

And this is my controller

```
1. [Route("{InsertRoadMap}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public mdRoadMapCallBack InsertRoadMap(mdEvent _mdEvent){
            mdRoadMapCallBack _mdRoadMapCallBack = new mdRoadMapCallBack();

            return _mdRoadMapCallBack;
        }
2. [Route("{UpdateRoadMap}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public mdRoadMapCallBack UpdateRoadMap(mdEvent _mdEvent)
        {
            mdRoadMapCallBack _mdRoadMapCallBack = new mdRoadMapCallBack();

            return _mdRoadMapCallBack;
        }
```

What is wrong ? Please help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Route` attribute doesn't seems to be implemented correctly.

Use it like this instead -

```
[Route("api/mycontroller/InsertRoadMap")]

[Route("api/mycontroller/UpdateRoadMap")]
```

Now you can browse like this - http://server/api/mycontroller/InsertRoadMap

You can also use `RoutePrefix` attribute at controller level so that you do not have to repeat `api` for every method.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
```

And then you can set routes like -

```
[Route("mycontroller/InsertRoadMap")]

[Route("mycontroller/UpdateRoadMap")]
```

See [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2?__hstc=250130137.d519671a34e3a56a4c773f89949c75cd.1488067200081.1488067200082.1488067200083.1&__hssc=250130137.1.1488067200084&__hsfp=528229161#prefixes) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) some more information on attribute routing

Comment: Hi Yogi, Thank you so much. Are you some document to set route config 1 time. i don't want to set this every my controller file

Comment: @user3001046 - Update my answer with some links on attribute routing. Hope that helps